# Solving Schwarzian derivative differential equation in Hollowood & Kumar paper

Tags: black-holes, conformal-field-theory, ads-cft, anti-de-sitter-spacetime

I Was re-deriving Hollowood & Kumar paper ([here is arXiv link of it)](https://arxiv.org/abs/2004.14944) which is about Anti-De Sitter Black-Holes with JT Gravity, anyway I got a problem with solving a schwarzian derivative differential equation in 3.19 of this paper which gives 3.22 solution without much explanation. I would be grateful if you could help me. i will attach images that needed in case you don't have access to paper.
in 3.19 image you see equation i'm trying to solve,in 2.20 gives us k definition,in 3.22 the answer we get and in 3.16 all information we need.

[image: this is 3.19 equation i'm trying to solve here k is defined in 2.20]
[image: 2.20 relation]
[image: here is the answer which it gives in 3.22]
[image: and these are rest of needed info on 3.16]

Comment: Hey fysh96, welcome to Phys.SE. Could you please whatever is in the pictures, on the post itself (with MathJax), so that it somebody in the future with a similar question can search for it and land on your question and its answers?

Comment: As for the solution of the differential equation, I suspect Mathematica solved it

Comment: @ɪdɪətstrəʊlə I gave this equation to mathematica but it can't solve it do you have any link with solution in it?

Answer (score 0):

The Schwarzian is defined as
$$
\{f(t), t\} = \left(\frac{f''(t)}{f'(t)}\right)' - \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{f''(t)}{f'(t)}\right)^2 = \frac{f'''(t)}{f'(t)} - \frac{3}{2}\left(\frac{f''(t)}{f'(t)}\right)^2,
$$
as you can see in eq. (3.9). The authors propose as a particular solution (you can check it out) of eq. (3.19)
$$
\hat{f}(t) = \alpha \frac{K_\nu(\nu z)}{I_\nu(\nu z)}, \qquad  \nu=\frac{2\pi}{\beta k}, \qquad z=\sqrt{\frac{E_\text{shock}}{E_\beta}}e^{-k(t-t_0)/2},
$$
where $\alpha$ is a normalization constant and $I_n(x)$ and $K_n(x)$ are the modified Bessel functions of the [first](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html) and [second](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselFunctionoftheSecondKind.html) kind, respectively. Then, you can try to seek for your general solution applying a [Möbius transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation)
$$
f(t) = \frac{A\hat{f}(t) + B}{C\hat{f}(t) + D}
$$
to your particular solution $\hat{f}(t)$ (this [general example](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28third%20derivative%20%28a*f%28x%29%2Bb%29%2F%28c*f%28x%29%2Bd%29%29%2F%28first%20derivative%20%28a*f%28x%29%2Bb%29%2F%28c*f%28x%29%2Bd%29%29%20-%201.5*%28%20%28second%20derivative%20%28a*f%28x%29%2Bb%29%2F%28c*f%28x%29%2Bd%29%29%2F%28first%20derivative%20%28a*f%28x%29%2Bb%29%2F%28c*f%28x%29%2Bd%29%29%20%29%5E2) may help you to convince yourself). See eq. (3.21) and the appendix B of the article to solve the constants $A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$, being mandatory that $AD-BC\neq0$. If you want a more detailed description, I'm all ears!